# SSRS data source windows authentication

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to create a report with a data source credentials: Windows Authentication. According to the Wizard it says: kerberos delegation might be required.
My question is: has anyone been able to get windows Authentication working without Kerberos?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No is the short answer. If you want the data source connection to authenticate with the credentials of the user running the report this will be a double hop situation that requires delegation.

Have a look at creating an SPN for the SSRS service account that will impersonate (delegate) authentication for you.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb735885.aspx

Your only other option is to save some service account credentials into a shared data source that the report server will use as a set of Windows credentials if you tick the box to do so.

Eg:

[image]

Ps. This screen shot was from SQL 2008. The options look a little different in SQL 2016.